# Testing a React with React-Router v.5, useHistory, useSelector and useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, enzyme, history.js, react-testing-library

I struggle with writing a proper test for a component that protects some routes and programatically redirects unauthorized users. The component looks like this:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { isAuthed } from 'redux/selectors/auth';

const mapState = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: isAuthed(state),
});

const LoginShield = ({ children }) => {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useSelector(mapState);
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isAuthenticated) {
      history.push('/login');
    }
  }, [isAuthenticated]);

  return children;
};

export default LoginShield;
```

I basically would like to check that the component redirects unauthenticated user and doesn't redirect an authenticated user (two basic test cases). I tried several approaches using Jest/Enzyme or Jest/ReactTestingLibrary and cannot find a good solution.

For now my test is a mess but I will share it so that someone can show me where the problem lays:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import rootReducer from 'redux/reducers';
import LoginShield from 'components/LoginShield/LoginShield';

describe('LoginShield component', () => {
  let wrapper;
  let historyMock;

  beforeEach(() => {
    const initialState = { auth: { loginId: 'Foo' } };
    const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState);
    historyMock = {
      push: jest.fn(),
      location: {},
      listen: jest.fn(),
    };
    jest.mock('react-redux', () => ({
      useSelector: jest.fn(fn => fn()),
    }));
    wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={historyMock}>
          <LoginShield>
            <h5>Hello Component</h5>
          </LoginShield>
        </Router>
      </Provider>,
    );
  });

  it('renders its children', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('h5').text()).toEqual('Hello Component');
  });

  it('redirects to the login page if user is not authenticated', async () => {
    await act(async () => {
      await Promise.resolve(wrapper);
      await new Promise(resolve => setImmediate(resolve));
      wrapper.update();
    });
    // is the above necessary?


    console.log(historyMock.push.mock.calls);
    // returns empty array

    // ... ? 

  });

  it('doesn`t redirect authenticated users', () => {
    // .... ?
  });
});
```

Any tips are more than welcome! Thank you in advance. :)